# some jQuery/javascript help. Add items to optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select, optgroup

I have an array called tmp

var tmp = ["05", "13", "27"];

if an option value is equal to a value within tmp, I want to add that option to a particular optgroup, else add it to the other optgroup. I keep getting everything added to optgroup #2, except the option with the value "27". What am I doing incorrectly?

```
    var groups = $("optgroup");
    $("option").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        for (var x = 0; x < tmp.length; x++) {
            var isMatch = (tmp[x] === value);
            if (isMatch) {
                $(this).appendTo($(groups[0]));
            } else if (value.length > 0) {
                $(this).appendTo($(groups[1]));
            }
        }

    });
```

Thanks for any pointers to correct this.

~ck in San Diego

Comment: How to get optgroup of specific select?Like if i have 2 select with 2 optgroups in both of them then how could i get optgroup of first select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a break after each appendTo statement so that you don't keep comparing the option to all tmp values.

```
var groups = $("optgroup");    
    $("option").each(function() {        
       var value = $(this).val();        
       for (var x = 0; x < tmp.length; x++) {            
            var isMatch = (tmp[x] === value);            
            if (isMatch) {                
                  $(this).appendTo($(groups[0]));            
                  break;
            } else if (value.length > 0) {                
                  $(this).appendTo($(groups[1]));            
                  break;
            }        
       }    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
$(this).appendTo($(groups[1]));
```

can be changed to

```
$(this).appendTo(groups[1]);
```

you don't need to wrap the element again into a jQuery object in order to append to it, a HTMLElement will work fine.

Do you have the HTML that you're using and where are your `<option>` elements that you are checking the value of?

**EDIT:**

I've rewritten your code slightly and this works correctly (N.B. appending won't work in IE6 and I believe 7 and 8 too - In IE the innerHTML property for a select element is readonly, so use createElement or the Option constructor to create options),

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/oxiro)**. add **/edit** to the URL to see the code. I have the option elements in an array in the working example, I assume that you have them in a similar structure.

```
var groups = $("optgroup");
$('options').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    if (tmp.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
        $this.appendTo(groups[0]);
    } 
    else if (val.length > 0) {
        $this.appendTo(groups[1]);
    }
});
```